# Change the image with JS every time the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement the following:
Change the image every time i click the button "next".
Right now the code gives me the very last image from the array `book` just after I click the button `next` once. Is there a way it can be done?

HTML code:

```
<body>
  <div class="main_page">
  <button type="button" id="start">Start</button>
  <button type="button" id="next">Next</button> 
  </div>
</body>
```

JS code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

let book = [
    {
    name: 'page1',
    img: 'img/page1.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'page2',
    img: 'img/page2.png'
    },
    {
    name: 'page3',
    img: 'img/page3.png'
    }
] 

const main_page = document.querySelector('.main_page');// with this variable I have conttrol of
                                                    // div with class .main_page

let mainImg = document.createElement('img') // similar to HTML tag <img>. this var-ble creates <img> tag in HTML Document
mainImg.setAttribute('src', book[0].img) // making attribute to <img> tag through JavaScript    
main_page.appendChild(mainImg);// appending <img> tag to the div with class main_page
let next = document.getElementById('next');

const turnPage = (count) =>{
    //if(mainImg.getAttribute("src") == 'img/page2.png') alert("hey")//mainImg.src = {firstpage}
    next.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if(mainImg.getAttribute("src") == book[count].img){
            //alert("hey")
             mainImg.src = book[count+1].img
        }})
}

 
for(let i = 0; i< book.length; i++){
    turnPage(i);
}


})
```

Comment: Declare `count` in the outer scope, and just do `mainImg.src = book[++count % 3].img;`, and not anything else in the event handler. The loop is not needed at all, a single listener will do.

Comment: What goes wrong with your current code is, that it attaches three click listeners to the button, and all the listeners are executed when the button is clicked, resulting to only the last image being shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems with your code, as others have pointed out. As [Teemu said](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu), you are adding 3 click listeners to the button. You also need to put the `turn page` function into your listener, instead of calling it outside. These are the main changes you need:

**1:** You need to declare a variable outside of the listeners and any loops to keep count of the pages

```
    let count = 0;
```

**2:** Add a listener that will call your `turnpage` function on each click. In that listener, you need to check that the next page isn't greater than the total number of pages before calling `turnPage`- otherwise you will get an error when the code tries to access the image from a non-existent page.

(You could instead start again at page 1, but as you have a **Start** button I assumed that you will intend to use that instead of having a continuous loop).

```
    next.addEventListener('click', () => {
       if ((count+1) < book.length)
          turnPage(count);
       count++;
    })
```

**3:** Finally, your `turnPage` function just needs to set up the next image

```
    const turnPage = (count) => {
        mainImg.src = book[count + 1].img
    }
```

**Here is the full working snippet:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  let book = [{
      name: 'page1',
      img: 'https://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-200-200-9.jpg'
    },
    {
      name: 'page2',
      img: 'https://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-200-200-10.jpg'
    },
    {
      name: 'page3',
      img: 'https://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-200-200-4.jpg'
    }
  ]


  const main_page = document.querySelector('.main_page'); // with this variable I have conttrol of
  // div with class .main_page

  let mainImg = document.createElement('img') // similar to HTML tag <img>. this var-ble creates <img> tag in HTML Document
  mainImg.setAttribute('src', book[0].img) // making attribute to <img> tag through JavaScript    
  main_page.appendChild(mainImg); // appending <img> tag to the div with class main_page
  let next = document.getElementById('next');



  // set up your listener to turn the page on each click
  next.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let count = 0;    // declare your variable for page count
    // check  if the next page is greater than the total number of pages
    if ((count+1) < book.length)
        turnPage(count);
    count++;  
  })

  // your turnPage function
  const turnPage = (count) => {
    if (mainImg.getAttribute("src") == book[count].img) {
        mainImg.src = book[count + 1].img
    }
  }


})
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main_page">
    <button type="button" id="start">Start</button>
    <button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

FYI I'm not sure what this line is for, but I've left it in, in case you need it for something you haven't included here:

```
if (mainImg.getAttribute("src") == book[count].img) {
```

Also, you could just use the count variable in your pageTurn without passing it in in the click listener. You could check if you are the the end in there - it all depends on how this fits in with the rest of what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

What Teemu said in the comments is right. I can't comment as my reputation is low. So providing the code here. Just remove turnPage function definition and for loop. And replace it with the code below.

```
let count = 0, len = book.length;
next.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(mainImg.getAttribute("src") == book[count].img){
    count = (count + 1) % len;
    mainImg.src = book[count].img
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use array to store your image and then display it in your codes**
But you also have to make sure you use `<img src="">` tag

*Example*

```
<img src="" id="myImage">
<br />
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>

//JavaScript Codes

//Get HTML Elements
let images = [];
let img = document.querySelector("#myImage");
let button = document.querySelector("#next");
let defaultIndex = 0;

//Make a function to be executed once you click the button
function makeIt() {

  //Make sure defaultIndex won't be above your array
  if (defaultIndex < images.length) {

    //Then go to the next image using incrementation
    defaultIndex += 1;

    //Assign your new value to the img tag
    img.src = images[defaultIndex];

}
```

You can even make **previous** feature by using decrement.

I hope this will help you. If you find any mistake, feel free to correct!